# Why is my Vim starting in replacemode?

Tags: vim, configuration

I may have accidentally changed some setting but now I can't figure out what it is.

Behavior:

- Whenever I edit an existing file, Vim starts in replace (`R`) mode. This is new as of this week.
- Whenever I do `vim nonExistantFile.txt`, Vim starts in normal mode

Steps so far to diagnose:

1. `/etc/vimrc` has nothing relevant, and specifically does not contain `startreplace`
2. `/home/<myuser>/.vimrc` has nothing relevant, and specifically does not contain `startreplace`
3. `alias` shows nothing `vim` related

Platform info:

- Vim version 7.3.1314
- Windows 7 64-Bit
- 32 Bit Cygwin and Vim binary

Other *potentially* relevant information:

- Some time ago (before this started happening) I copied `/etc/vimrc` from my CentOS 6.4 machine into the Cygwin `/etc/vimrc`
- I edited some binary files recently

I'm pretty stumped, I can't think of anything else to try.

**Update:**

- I have narrowed the problem down to this `/etc/vimrc` snippet
- Oddly commenting out EITHER of these two commands solves the problem

**Vimrc snippet** (note: this does have unix line endings):

```
" Only do this part when compiled with support for autocommands
if has("autocmd")
  "<snip>
  " When editing a file, always jump to the last cursor position
  autocmd BufReadPost *
  \ if line("'\"") > 0 && line ("'\"") <= line("$") |
  \   exe "normal! g'\"" |
  \ endif
  " don't write swapfile on most commonly used directories for NFS mounts or USB sticks
  autocmd BufNewFile,BufReadPre /media/*,/mnt/* set directory=~/tmp,/var/tmp,/tmp
  "<snip>
endif
```

Comment: Just a thought, the centos newline might not be compatible with win. Can you grab another vimrc?

Comment: Try to delete your `.viminfo` file. I had a similar problem once and it solved it. My theory is that `.viminfo` contained some rogue command which was executed at startup.

Comment: @KevinDTimm You may be on to something

Comment: @KevinDTimm nope I used `unix2dos` on the file and it choked

Answer (score 8):

I mapped `nnoremap <ESC> :nohlsearch<CR>` in my `.vimrc` and that caused this behaviour.

Mapping this to `<Enter>` solved the problem for me.

Comment: Wow thank you! This was causing replace mode problem caused above and arrow keys to type A/B/C/D for some weird reason. I have raised this issue here https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/3080

Comment: This is exactly the problem I had! How did you figure out that it was causing it ?

Comment: I bisected my vimrc and found that this changed caused the behavior. Pretty damn weird, ans it took me quite a while to find. But it was driving me nuts as you can believe.

Comment: This caused/fixed the issue for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

check ~/.exrc files for initial settings, there must be a flag setting your vi into REPLACE mode at startup!

http://alvinalexander.com/unix/edu/un010003/

cheers!

Comment: Good idea, but I don't have a `~/.exrc` nor do I have `/etc/exrc`

Answer (score 0):

I added a few newlines and swapped the two commands in `/etc/vimrc` that seemed to be causing the problem... and this seemed to fix it. I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

The following seemed to fix this problem for me. I think that there was some autocommand code that interfered with the cursor position restore, so clearing out previous autocommands as below fixed the problem for me:

```
function! ResCur()
  if line("'\"") <= line("$")
    normal! g`"
    return 1
  endif
endfunction

augroup resCur
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufWinEnter * call ResCur()
augroup END
```

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Restore_cursor_to_file_position_in_previous_editing_session